# what is the laravel eloquent equivalent of my SQL Count GroupBy query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

this is my sql query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM anuncios WHERE user_id = 2 and user_id = 3 or estado = "Activo" GROUP BY user_id
```

results in the total number of active "anunios" for each user_id;

but trying the same query with laravel eloquent brings me the total of all the data without grouping them by user_id

this is my query with laravel eloquent

```
$anuncios = Anuncios::whereIn('user_id',$ids)->where('estado','Activo')->groupBy('user_id')->get()->count();
```

Comment: _WHERE user_id = 2 and user_id = 3_ How can both be true at the same time?

Comment: I made that query with sql where user_id = 2 and user_id = 3 since at the moment in my users table I only have 3 and for practical purposes I put them (because I know they exist) unless the query has an error and instead of "And" should be "or"

Comment: You don't need the `->get()` part in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling `->get()` you are doing a `count()` on a Collection. If you want to run it as a query, you need to call it on a `QueryBuilder` by removing the `->get()`.

To achieve it in pure Eloquent, you can use the following:

```
$anuncios = Anuncios::select('user_id','estado')
    ->whereIn('user_id',$ids)
    ->where('estado','Activo')
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->count();
```